# Numbers from txt file aren't sorted

Tags: javascript, sorting, discord

If I use `[3, 8, -10, 23, 19, -4, -14, 27].sort((a,b)=>a-b)` it works.
But if I use...

```
leaderboard = (fs.readFileSync('leaderboard.txt', 'utf-8'))
[leaderboard].sort((a,b)=>a-b)
```

...it just sends the numbers unsorted.

leaderboard.txt = `3, 8, -10, 23, 19, -4, -14, 27`

Comment: @radlaz dont know. how can i convert it?

Comment: take a look at the answer below. that's all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The leaderboard is just a string when it's read from a file.
Assuming that the file contains '3, 8, -10, ...', you should first split the string to an array. then cast item(with type string) to number and then sort.

```
const sortedLeaderBoard = leaderboard
  .split(', ')
  .map(Number)
  .sort((a, b) => a - b);
console.log(sortedLeaderBoard);
```

is my assumption correct?